# .net core hangfire run a specific task

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, hangfire

I am using hangfire. and I need a task that runs once as below. how can i do this?

```
 BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => new EmailService().SendEmail("new email.."), "10 05 * * *");
```

Error

```
 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
```

Error   CS1662  Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type My.API

Comment: `SendEmail` method has any return type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately we can't see the code for your SendEmail method, but it should be something like this and it should work.

```
public Task SendEmail()
{
    // Send email

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

To schedule:

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => new EmailService().SendEmail(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
}
```

Comment: hello, it is as you said. but how can i set it as a specific date. ie how can I set it as hour/day/month/year.

Comment: BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => new EmailService().SendEmail("new message "), "10 05 * * *");

Comment: You can do that by doing the following:             
BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => new EmailService().SendEmail(), new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2021, 10, 22)));

Comment: thank you very much mate but how can i add the clock

Comment: DateTime(2021, 10, 22, 15:00)))

Comment: When constructing the DateTime, "new DateTime()", the time parameters can be added as such: new DateTime(2021, 10, 22, 10, 30, 0) - this would result in the date and time being: 2021-10-22 10:30:00.